# HTML 5 video player doesn't allow to drag the player time line

Tags: html5-canvas, html5-video

I have created a web app using HTML5. There is a screen where I need to add videos dynamically to the webapp. I use HTML 5 video player for this and particular code is shown below. When the video is playing for the first time if I try to drag the time line of the player it won't functioning correctly. Instead it goes again back to the same previous position and continues to play the video. If video has been played at least once (if it is cached) I can drag the time line any where I want and video is starting to play from that particular time. Is there anyway that I can add this functionality when I'm loading it for the 1st time? Is there any specific HTML5 attribute for it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>

    <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
      <source src="video url goes here" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: I'm using wamp server

Comment: Are byte ranges request enabled?

Comment: Have you tried `preload`?

Comment: can u be more specific on byte ranges request and preload ? Anyway it seems like firefox is working fine for this

Comment: Byte ranges requests are a feature in HTTP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) that enable the server to give just "pieces" of the file, that was requested by the client. It must be enabled to make pseudostreaming working in a HTML5 player... If you're using Apache it should be enabled by default though. `Preload` is an attribute that can suggest to the browser what it has to do with a media file before the user has clicked to play it — if it should download it previously, or just the metadata, or nothing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload)

Answer (score 0):

No. Most browsers' players are still broken as far as direct URLs to videos are concerned. You'd have to implement a custom player and controls which starts streaming a new video and the server side takes a parameter such as ?time=xxx and returns the video starting from that point.